# How to send multiple parameters to the vertex shader on WebGL?

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, webgl

I'm following a tutorial on OpenGL (because WebGL tutorials are rare), where it uses the following syntax for multiple parameteres:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 color;

smooth out vec4 theColor;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
    theColor = color;
}
```

But the `layout (location = #)` syntax doesn't work on WebGL. What is the substitute for this?

Answer (score 10):

There are a number of things wrong with this shader if you intend to use it in WebGL.

For starters, WebGL is based on OpenGL ES 2.0, which uses a version of GLSL derived from 120.

Your `#version` directive is invalid for WebGL; you cannot use `in`, `out`, or `smooth` for vertex attributes or varying variables; there is no layout qualifier.

This will get you part of the way to fixing your shader:

```
#version 100

attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 color;

varying vec4 theColor;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
    theColor    = color;
}
```

But you will also need to bind the attribute locations for `position` and `color` in your code (before linking your shaders - see [`glBindAttribLocation (...)`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindAttribLocation.xml)). If you are having difficulty finding tutorials for WebGL / ESSL, you can re-use many OpenGL tutorials that were written for GLSL version 120 or older.

You can read the offical specification for OpenGL ES 2.0's GLSL (ESSL) [here](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf). At the very least, have a look at the introductory section because it contains a lot of useful information.

Comment: *Update: (8/22/2015)* WebGL 2 now supports OpenGL ES 3 and GLSL version 3 (with some restrictions). The `layout` specification is still unsupported (or at least seems to be). I use `gl.getAttribLocation(program, "position")` to fetch the actual linked index (after `gl.linkProgram` is called). You can use `gl.bindAttribLocation` to fix this index (before `gl.linkProgram` is called), but it is not necessary.

Comment: @wcochran: Nice, thank you for pointing this out. I will have to take a look at the new WebGL 2 spec in my free time. Interestingly though, for GLSL ES 3.00 `layout` qualifiers do exist and `location` for vertex attributes and fragment shader outputs should be valid. It is perhaps the case that the GLSL compiler is strictly conforming to the `#version` directive; you would need to write `#version 300 es` to ensure proper behavior.